# Angular 2+ do operation when any input in formGroup is touched

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Reactive Forms in Angular. I want to do an operation when any form input is touched in a formGroup. As `touched` property of `formGroup` cannot be observed, how can I achieve a similar result?

I am currently watching for `valueChanges` but it does not trigger when a touch event occurs.

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.accountForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    this.displayMessage = this.genericValidator.processMessages(this.accountForm);
  });
}
```

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43381131/6294072