# Check when a field gets touched in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been doing some research on this, but still can't find what I'm looking for. I have a form and would like to capture the touched event. My code looks like this:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res =>{
  if(res !== null){
    console.log('message');
  }
})
```

If I were to enter a value I can console the value out, but I want to be able to show a message like "field has been touched" when I touch a field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to observe touched event on Angular 2 NgForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337024/how-to-observe-touched-event-on-angular-2-ngform)

Answer (score 1):

You could use input events to call a function when the user has clicked in a field, entered a value, hit the enter key, or exited a field, depending on what you want specifically.

```
<input #textfield 
(keyup.enter)="onEnter(textfield.value)" 
(blur)="onBlur(textfield.value)"
>

onEnter(value) {
console.log("User entered this: ",value);
}

onBlur(value) {
console.log("User existed field: ",value);
}
```

Comment: @Stephene R. Smith This doesn't handle the touched event on a field

Comment: My understanding is that a field is ‘touched’ if a user has entered and exited a field without changing its value, so calling a function onBlur notifies you when the control has lost focus, and you could check its ‘dirty’ flag to see if the value was changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-custom-form-component',
  templateUrl: './custom-form-component.html',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: MyCustomFormComponent,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class MyCustomFormComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, DoCheck {

  private control: AbstractControl;

  private pristine = true;


  ngDoCheck (): void {
    if (this.pristine !== this.control.pristine) {
      this.pristine = this.control.pristine;
      if (this.pristine) {
        console.log('Marked as pristine!');
      }
    }
  }

}
```

This is what I found. This should work for touch also.

For more information https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17736

Comment: Can you provide a live demo on what your code does? It's still not clear to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solution works very smoothly based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/69363347/5063456

```js
const form = new FormControl('');
(form as any)._markAsTouched = form.markAsTouched;
(form as any).touchedChanges = new Subject();
form.markAsTouched = opts => {
  (form as any)._markAsTouched(opts);
  (form as any).touchedChanges.next('touched');
}; 

...

(form as any).touchedChanges.asObservable().subscribe(() => {
  // execute something when a form was marked as touched
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `ReactiveForms` check docs:

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl

It has some properties that you can use to determine if input was `touched`.

Comment: I already used that link, but it's still not clear to me how to capture the touched event from the component

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at the ng-touched CSS class and try to do it with that. You can try it with a combination of that and the form reference where you can check if the form state. I remember using that for form validation. It might not be what you're trying to do buy it might point you in the right direction.

in my CSS:

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I want to capture the tocuhed event from the component and NOT from css or the view

Comment: Sorry about that