# How to find where / when a FormControl was marked as touched

Tags: angular

I have a case where a FormControl gets marked as touched but don't know when and where.

Already searched the code for all .markAsTouched() and .setValue() and set breakpoints, but none are hit.

Is there a way to debug this?

Comment: Seems its can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337024/how-to-observe-touched-event-on-angular-2-ngform